# Website or Software for Molecular Orbital Rotations

Tags: organic-chemistry, inorganic-chemistry, pericyclic

Does anyone know what software or website allows viewers to see rotation of orbitals in a molecule such as conrotatory and disrotatory directions? I'm not an expert in this field sorry. I tried VR Molecules and Chemsketch but they don't go deeper in the molecular orbitals. I am studying pericyclic reactions, that's why.

Comment: Do not spend too much time identifying a program to visualize this like a movie.  Use your two fists and observe the relative move (take the thumbs as an indicator).  The closest example identified for a somewhat step-wise illustration (but lacking the orbitals) is a German tutorial already translated into English [here](http://www.chemgapedia.de/vsengine/vlu/vsc/en/ch/2/vlu/pericyclische_reaktionen/pericyclisch_elektrocyclisch.vlu/Page/vsc/en/ch/2/oc/reaktionen/formale_systematik/pericyclische_reaktionen/elektrocyclisch/stereochemie.vscml/Supplement/1.html).